# Unload a snowpark dataframe to external stage based on a filter

Tags: python-3.x, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I am currently running a bunch of queries on a snowflake table and dumping the data to an external stage using the following code in python, using snowflake-snowpark:

```
from snowflake.snowpark import Session

connection_parameters = {
            "account": "blah",
            "user": "user",
            "password": "pass",
            "role": "role",
            "warehouse": "blah",
            "database": "db",
            "schema": "schema"
        }
connection = Session.builder.configs(connection_parameters).create()
query = "select a, b, c from db.schema.table where a= 'val1"
df = connection.sql(query)

df.write.copy_into_location(external_stage, file_format_type="parquet", header=True, overwrite=True, single=False, MAX_FILE_SIZE=250 * 1024 * 1024)
```

Here the snowflake.snowpark.DataFrame just gets divided into chunks and gets unloaded. But what I want to do is group by the df based on column A and then dump each of the grouped dataframes into a separate file. The DataFrame.groupBy() method in snowpark documentation currently does not allow me to do loop over the grouped dfs and unload them individually, and I don't want to load the entire df into pandas (in memory) because it can tend to be very large. Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?